# Conditional probability and independence

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, discrete-data

Suppose A and Y are discrete dichotomous variables $(A=0,1; Y=0,1)$

If $Pr[Y=1|A=1] = Pr[Y=1|A=0]$, why can we conclude that $$Pr[Y=1|A=1] = Pr[Y=1|A=0] = Pr[Y = 1],$$ without knowing beforehand whether $A$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: If it is a homework, you should use the `[self-study]` tag and check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

By the law of total probability,
\begin{align}
Pr(Y=1) &= Pr(Y=1|A=1)Pr(A=1) + Pr(Y=1|A=0)Pr(A=0) \\
&=Pr(Y=1|A=1)Pr(A=1) + Pr(Y=1|A=1)(1-Pr(A=1))\\
\end{align}

Can you simplify the equations above?

Edit:

In the second equation, I have used the fact that we are given $$Pr(Y=1|A=0)=Pr(Y=1|A=1)$$

Comment: If you, in your equation, are only using the law of total probability, and not an indepedence property, the last part of the equation should read $Pr(Y=1\mid A=0)(1-Pr(A=1))$ and not $Pr(Y=1\mid A=1)(1-Pr(A=1))$. Otherwise the equivalence does not hold.

Comment: We are told $Pr(Y=1|A=0)=Pr(Y=1|A=0)$ isn't it?

Comment: I am assuming that you mean $Pr(Y=1\mid A=1) = Pr(Y=1 \mid A=0)$. Yes, we are. But my point is that we are using external information for that part of the calculation, and not just relying on the law of total probability. I would thus add somewhere in the writing that "where the last equality holds because, here,  $Pr(Y=1\mid A=1) = Pr(Y=1 \mid A=0)$" or something along those lines.

Comment: Let me add a remark there. Thanks for the feedback.